# google cloud messag server error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to create a simple chat application for device to device communication  using Google cloud messaging .. when i try to run the server side device to device code
As listed bellow

```
`

package com.javapapers.java.gcm;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

    @WebServlet("/GCMNotification")
    public class GCMNotification extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Put your Google API Server Key here
        private static final String GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY = "AIzaSyAJuusn84VR9d4jiedBSIy1pE4gQCh2IG0";
        static final String REGISTER_NAME = "name";
        static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";
        static final String TO_NAME = "toName";
        static final String REG_ID_STORE = "GCMRegId.txt";

        public GCMNotification() {
            super();
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(request, response);

        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String action = request.getParameter("action");

            if ("shareRegId".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {

                writeToFile(request.getParameter("name"),
                        request.getParameter("regId"));
                request.setAttribute("pushStatus",
                        "GCM Name and corresponding RegId Received.");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
                        .forward(request, response);

            } else if ("sendMessage".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {

                try {
                    String fromName = request.getParameter(REGISTER_NAME);
                    String toName = request.getParameter(TO_NAME);
                    String userMessage = request.getParameter(MESSAGE_KEY);
                    Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
                    Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                            .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage)
                            .addData(REGISTER_NAME, fromName).build();
                    Map<String, String> regIdMap = readFromFile();
                    String regId = regIdMap.get(toName);
                    Result result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus", result.toString());
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus",
                            "RegId required: " + ioe.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus", e.toString());
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
                        .forward(request, response);
            } else if ("multicast".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {

                try {
                    String fromName = request.getParameter(REGISTER_NAME);
                    String userMessage = request.getParameter(MESSAGE_KEY);
                    Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
                    Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                            .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage)
                            .addData(REGISTER_NAME, fromName).build();
                    Map<String, String> regIdMap = readFromFile();

                    List<String> regIdList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (Entry<String, String> entry : regIdMap.entrySet()) {
                        regIdList.add(entry.getValue());
                    }

                    MulticastResult multiResult = sender
                            .send(message, regIdList, 1);
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus", multiResult.toString());
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus",
                            "RegId required: " + ioe.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus", e.toString());
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
                        .forward(request, response);
            }
        }

        private void writeToFile(String name, String regId) throws IOException {
            Map<String, String> regIdMap = readFromFile();
            regIdMap.put(name, regId);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                    REG_ID_STORE, false)));
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : regIdMap.entrySet()) {
                out.println(entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue());
            }
            out.println(name + "," + regId);
            out.close();

        }

        private Map<String, String> readFromFile() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(REG_ID_STORE));
            String regIdLine = "";
            Map<String, String> regIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            while ((regIdLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] regArr = regIdLine.split(",");
                regIdMap.put(regArr[0], regArr[1]);
            }
            br.close();
            return regIdMap;
        }
    }
`
```

![It shows a error message like
this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YyEJ.png]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include json_simple.jar in the library path of your project. This library is used by the `com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender` class. The missing class (`ParseException`) belongs to that library.

Comment: thank you for your reply.... but still i couldn't get it... after importing json_simple.jar and gcm-server-1.0.2.jar

Comment: Thank you for your help but when i select the send push notification it shows